# VBA - Copy and Paste in next empty row on starting in Column B

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to have it copy from Data!A2:Z2 and paste in the 1st empty row on another sheet. However, column A has a formula and I'm looking for the first row where there is an empty cell in B to insert the data. So, if I have data through row 25, I would want it to copy the data and paste starting in cell B26. Of course the next time it runs it would paste in B27. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Show us what you have so far, we aren't here to solve your problems from scratch, but to help you debug issues that you've tried to do already.

Comment: Here is your syntax for copying over data between sheets: `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:Z2") = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A5:Z5")`  Read here to figure out how to get the next blank row http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-customize/what-does-lastrow-cellsrowscount-qendxluprow-do/6c28164c-66bf-49f2-91ec-f38bb66afcaa , when you get the row number of the next row, concatenate it into the assignment command, something like `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & myNextRow & ":Z" & myNextRow) = Worksheets("Sheet2")...etc` If you get stuck post a more detailed question?

Comment: Duplicate of this question which itself is a duplicate. A basic search would have shown this

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Sub gr47fgsdgf()
    Dim n As Long
    n = Sheets("other").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Sheets("Data").Range("A2:Z2").Copy Sheets("other").Range("B" & n)
End Sub
```